# data cleaning on SPSS for linear regression

Tags: linear-regression, spss, data-cleaning

I've got a large amount of data and I want to use the independent variables A and B to predict the dependent variable C by using multiple linear regression. But now some of the A and B are lacking values (it can be lacking A only, lacking B only or lacking both).

How can I process them so that my data is good for doing the prediction? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I get your problem.

Well, let's have look at the Command Syntax Reference for Linear Regression:

> By default, all cases in the active dataset with valid values for all
>   selected variables are used to compute the correlation matrix on which
>   the regression equations are based.

That means, all cases with missing values are excluded *automatically* from the analysis.